# Can we always perform SVD on the data matrix before doing high-dimensional logistic regression?

Tags: regression, classification, pca, svd, high-dimensional

So I'm using lasso logistic regression to classify my data.

My data matrix $X$ has dimension $n\times p$ for $p >> n$.

As $p$ is on the order of a billion, I expect to face some computational challenges when trying to run lasso logistic regression.

If I'm only interested in predictive performance, and I don't care about inference, is there any drawback to taking the SVD of

$$XX^T=U\Sigma^2U^T$$

and then simply applying lasso logistic regression to $U$?

As far as I can tell, all I've done is do a change of basis so that I'm only considering the $n-1$ dimensional affine space spanned by my data, and thus my classification algorithm should perform just as well.

**Edit**

It does appear that the above is correct, see the related question,

[Using SVD on features before SVM classification, when p >> N](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124344/28345)

Comment: Is $p$ the number of features or the number of observations? As the first dimension of $X$ it would ordinarily be taken as the latter, but your reference to $n-1$ dimensions suggests the former.  (But why $n-1$ and not $n$ or, if you throw in an intercept, $n+1$?)

Comment: @whuber, that was a typo, it should have been $n\times p$ (I'll correct). As for why $n-1$, that is the affine dimension of $n$ points, assuming no degeneracy. Although I guess I maybe wasn't clear that I was refering to that, rather than the $n$ dimensional space defined by $n$ vectors, I guess it's not a terribly important distinct to make in this context.

Comment: Affine dimension doesn't seem relevant either to SVD or this kind of model.  I agree the distinction between $n$ and $n-1$ looks unimportant when $n$ is huge, but the fact you were making it raised a flag suggesting the possibility of miscommunication.

Comment: @whuber, ya I meant that my reference to the $n-1$ affine dimension wasn't that important. But yah, $n$ isn't huge, $p$ is huge, and $n$ is (relatively) small.